# Arrival time of VY8783 to Barcelona–El Prat Airport from Liverpool John Lennon Airport on June 3, 2016?

Tags: air-travel, bcn, liverpool

Could you please tell me the arrival time of flight VY8783 to Barcelona–El Prat Airport from Liverpool John Lennon Airport on June 3, 2016?

We feel the delay was longer than is being stated by the airline.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a non-US date of 3 June, according to [flightstats](http://www.flightstats.com/) it arrived at 21:14, 214 minutes late. It was scheduled to arrive at 17:40. Runway arrival was 21:09, but that is not relevant for EU261 compensation purposes. According to recent rulings (and perhaps earlier ones too!), arrival time means the time the doors open on arrival at the gate.